# Xidel: How to printout the node instead of the value?

Tags: xpath, xidel

html example:

```
<p class="si-price" data-price="910000.00">Rp 910.000</p>
```

so in xidel, i do this:

```
xidel -se '(//p[@class="si-price"])[1]' 'https://www.anekalogam.co.id/id'
```

what I want is `910000` which is in the `data-price` instead of `Rp 910.000`

can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
xidel -se '(//p[@class="si-price"])/@data-price' 'https://www.anekalogam.co.id/id'
```

Output:

```
905000.00
1750000.00
2595000.00
4300000.00
8550000.00
21250000.00
42400000.00
84000000.00
```